# Sending key stroke from client to server

Tags: java, client-server

I am making a project, I have built a Server and a client. This is currently in the development stage and still doesn't do much. I just waned to know if its possible to send keystroke over the network from the client to the server?

I have implemented keylistener to my client class. That's all done, the question is, how would I send keystroke to the server, and how would the server receive the keystrokes? How will I convert keystrokes to bytes?

Will I still use getInputStream() and getOutputStream()?

Comment: There are many options: Sockets, HTTP, WebSockets, ... What are you actually trying to do?

Comment: You will need to define how to move your keystrokes in one of the many possible transport streams.  The simplest - for now while you are learning - is possibly to make a http request from the client to the server for each keypress.

Comment: Thorbjorn Ravn Andersen, yeah I was actually had that in mind, but I don't think it would still be a good practice. Lutz Horn, I am building a raspberry pi robot, based in java, I want to be able to control it from a client, while the server will do all the processing and controlling the GPIO's energy flow

Comment: How often do you want to transmit a keypress? Can there be a lag?

Comment: Every time the key is pressed down or holded down

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would consider sending a key code to the server. See [`KeyStroke.getKeyCode()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/AWTKeyStroke.html#getKeyCode%28%29). This is an integer value.

There are many examples on the Internet of how to send an `int` from a client to a server (e.g. [send/read int in a client/server app](http://www.java-forums.org/new-java/5112-send-read-int-client-server-app.html)). Take a look and pick one that matches your use case.